# Using a iMac (2011) in Target Display Mode with Dell XPS 15 equipped with Thunderbolt 3

Tags: external-display, dell-xps, imac, thunderbolt, usb-c

I have a Dell XPS 9550, equipped with a Thunderbolt 3/ USB-C port. I am trying to use my iMac 2011 as a target display.

I read that this can only be done using the Thunderbolt (V1 on iMac) port, and bought the Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2/1 adapter from Apple. Using this configuration, I am not able to put my iMac in TDM.

I thought that as long as the whole protocol is kept Thunderbolt, I can do this. Any help? Or is this not compatible?

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: No, just a bweep - whenever I press the appropriate combo to put the mac in TDM, and nothing on Dell. Dell does say that the thunderbolt device is not recognized, and can be optimized. Nothing on mac at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target Display Mode on Thunderbolt-equipped iMacs is a Mac-to-iMac, macOS-to-macOS thing only. [Apple’s online support article on TDM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) even says it won’t work if the sending Mac is booted into Windows via Boot Camp, or if the sending Mac doesn't have a user logged in.

I don’t think there’s any hope of getting a Dell laptop to work as the sender.

If you had a pre-Thunderbolt iMac that supported TDM (2009 or 2010 iMac), I think it would have acted as a pretty standard DisplayPort display. Unfortunately that changed when Thunderbolt came along.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I thought that this was just the war between PC and Apple, and they did not test it/ include the details.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for sure to use an iMac (those that support Target Display Mode) as the monitor for a PC.

For the past 3 years, I have used a 27 inch late 2010 iMac in TDM for two different work laptops of mine (one HP Elitebook with DisplayPort, and one Dell laptop with the new TB16 Thunderbolt docking station, although I used the Display Port on the back of the docking station to the DP on the iMac).  Both have worked fine.  I've just purchased a used 27 inch Late 2013 iMac and I am now trying to use Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C connector) from the back of the Dell dock to Thunderbolt 2 (which is the same form factor as Display Port connector on the back of the iMac).

I believe I'll need this [Apple Thunderbolt 3 to 2 adapter and a Thunderbolt 2 cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter).

Comment: The 2009 and 2010 iMacs predate Thunderbolt, and became DisplayPort displays when in TDM, so that's why your old iMac worked with your non-Mac sender. I think the Thunderbolt iMacs do something less standard. Please remember to come back and update your Answer once you find out whether or not your 2013 iMac works as a TDM display for your Dell.

Comment: Well, the TB16 docking station doesn't work so far with the Apple TB 3 to 2 adapter.  I get a message as though it doesn't have enough power.  "Try improving your USB connection".  I'm heading back to BestBuy to try and find a thunderbolt to HDMI adapter/cable since the TB16 has HDMI as well.  Doubt it will work though...  Loosing hope.